# AdMob ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error

Tags: java, android, admob, exoplayer, admob-rewardedvideoad

I am using AdMob in my Android app. Ads are usually working fine.

However, sometimes I get following errors when trying to load a RewardedAd. It often appears when loading multiple (different) ads. Once this error appears, no other AdMob ads including Interstitials can show anymore until the app cold starts again. The problem is that my app permanently needs to run a background service which makes the app never restart.

Is there any way I can fix this error in runtime without restarting the app?

```
D/CCodecConfig: read media type: audio/mp4a-latm
I/CCodecConfig: query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)
I/CCodecConfig: query failed after returning 19 values (BAD_INDEX)

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Renderer error.
com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.c
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.N(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.video.h.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.z(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.n.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:42)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.b: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.vp9.dec, Format(1, null, video/x-vnd.on2.vp9, -1, null, [640, 360, -1.0], [-1, -1])
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.N(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:19)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:4) 
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.video.h.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1) 
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.z(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3) 
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.n.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:42) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
 Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.Exynos.vp9.dec, error 0xfffffff4
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1961)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1938)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.N(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:9)
```

and immediately afterwards

```
W/Ads: Precache error
com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.c
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.N(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.video.h.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.z(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.n.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:42)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
 Caused by: com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.b: Decoder init failed: OMX.Exynos.vp9.dec, Format(1, null, video/x-vnd.on2.vp9, -1, null, [640, 360, -1.0], [-1, -1])
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.N(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:19)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:4) 
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.video.h.G(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1) 
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.z(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3) 
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.n.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:42) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
 Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Failed to initialize OMX.Exynos.vp9.dec, error 0xfffffff4
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1961)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.createByCodecName(MediaCodec.java:1938)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.exoplayer3.mediacodec.c.N(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:9)

I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 0
W/Ads: Failed to preload url VIDEO_... Exception: ExoPlayer was released during preloading.
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
```